# verify signature with bouncycastle failed with NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle, nosuchelementexception

I want to verify a signature made with bouncycastle library. This is my code for verifying the cmssigneddata object.

```
public static void verifySignature(CMSSignedData sigData){
    Store store = sigData.getCertificates();
            SignerInformationStore signers = sigData.getSignerInfos();

            Collection c = signers.getSigners();
            Iterator it = c.iterator();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next();

                Collection certCollection = store.getMatches(signer.getSID());
                Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();

                X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
                X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().getCertificate(certHolder);

                if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().build(cert))) {
                    System.out.println("verified correct");
                }
                System.out.println("not verified");
    }
```

I get the exception ***Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)***
What is the problem here? Seems like the problem is the ArrayList?

**EDIT**
Inserted a while loop for certIt.next()

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
            SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next();

            Collection certCollection = store.getMatches(signer.getSID());
            Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();

            while (certIt.hasNext()) {
                X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
                X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().getCertificate(certHolder);

                if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().build(cert))) {
                    System.out.println("verified correct");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("not verified");
                }
            }
```

**EDIT**
generating CMSSignedData

```
public static CMSSignedData sign() throws Exception {
        byte[] file = fileChooser();
        store = KeyStore.getInstance(storeType);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(storePathKey));
        store.load(in, storePassword);
        in.close();

        Key priv = store.getKey("Subject", storePassword);
        System.out.println(priv.toString() + "priv string");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) store.getCertificate("Subject");
        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(sigAlgo).build((RSAPrivateKey) priv);

        // Build cms (sign data) - Cryptographic Message Syntax
        CMSTypedData data = new CMSProcessableByteArray(file);
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build())
                .build(signer, cert));
        CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(data, true);

        return sigData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
 X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();`

You are calling next without checking for hasNext

Comment: I call hasNext() in the while loop.

Comment: You got two iterators in your code `Collection c = signers.getSigners();
            Iterator it = c.iterator();` and `Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();`

Comment: Do I need a while or an if loop?

Comment: If you want to run through the whole list of certificates and verify then you will need a while loop. Else if you want to just use the first one just use if condition to check if you have a matching certificate and use the first one.

Comment: Thank you. I added it above but I don't get into the second while loop with the code. What is the problem?

Comment: @nolags that means your collection is empty.

Comment: so what do I have to change in my sign() method? to get a working collection?

Answer (score 0):

`Collection certCollection = store.getMatches(signer.getSID());` returns an empty `Collection`. That's why you cannot iterate it.

Are you sure the argument `CMSSignedData sigData` was constructed correctly? Try to see what do get from `store.getMatches(null);`?

Comment: I get an empty array.. added my sigData construction above.